# Como integrar el SDK de Mercado Pago en Symfony 5.2

Tags: php, symfony, mercadopago, sdk

Al parecer genera conflicto de versiones pero no se como solucionarlo, les paso el error que me daponiendo:

```
composer require mercadopago/dx-php
```

```
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update mercadopago/dx-php
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - mercadopago/dx-php[2.2.0, ..., 2.2.1] require doctrine/common ^2.6 -> found doctrine/common[v2.6.0, ..., 2.13.x-dev] but the package is fixed to 3.1.2 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
    - Root composer.json requires mercadopago/dx-php ^2.2 -> satisfiable by mercadopago/dx-php[2.2.0, 2.2.1].

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
```

Tambien probé con composer require mercadopago/dx-php --with-all-dependencies pero me da error.

Alguna ayuda?

Comment: Tienes en tu `composer.json` la dependencia `doctrine/common`? con qué versión? Tal vez podrías agregar la parte del `require` de tu `composer.json`

Comment: En el composer.json no me figura, pero parece que cuando se instala symfony 5 pone una en un paquete versión 3.1.2 ahí es donde cuando quiero ponerla con require en el json genera conflicto y dice que tiene que ser la version 2.6 para que funcione el mercadopago/dx-php . No se si hay forma de anularla o cambiarla para que me tome el sdk.